# Twitter BootStrap, Sticky footer and 100% height dive give the page extra unnecessary scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap (RTL) with Sticky Footer and I have two columns in one row with 100% height. But when I open the page it has unnecessary scrollbar and I don't know why.

You can see it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/aCsyH/).

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid mainContainer">
    <div class="row-fluid full-height">
        <div class="span3 sidebar itemContainer full-height">
            <h2>ابزارهای در دست‌رس</h2>
            @ToolsList.GetToolsList(this, Model)
        </div>
        <div class="span9 main itemContainer full-height">
            <h2>بدنه</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer itemContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                توسط احمدعلی شفیعی
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

and This is my css StyleSheet (beside bootstrap's default code)

```
* {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main {
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.itemContainer {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.mainContainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -40px;
}

.ToolItem {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer, .push {
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
}

.footer {
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have box-sizing: border-box in your CSS? You can apply it to your universal selector. Not sure if this fixes your problem, but I see you have padding and borders in your css

Comment: @RobR The upper css is all I have in my style!

Comment: It's hard for me to know without seeing an example, but try adding to your: * { box-sizing: border-box }. Include web prefixes also, thanks

Comment: Try adding bootstrap to jsfiddle or jsbin from this cdn: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: @RobR The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/aCsyH/) now

Comment: @mg1075 Thanks! I did that it's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/aCsyH/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your description i think you want a **sticky footer and a height 100% screen**...

Check the documnetation and examples on Twitter Bootstrap:-

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples

Their is an example for a sticky footer:-

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

For this you have to download the documentations of Twitter Bootstrap:-

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

Hope this works for you...
Thanks...

Comment: My StickyFooter is like what is in the example. and they have no documentation about 100% height

Comment: the example of sticky footer i mentioned is height 100%, do you want height 100% of footer container as the screen?

Comment: it only have `height: 60px;` for `#push, #footer` not `height: 100%;`

Comment: what do you mean by that, an element is `height:auto` by default it takes the size of the inner element on that container, what are you taking to do for this?

Comment: where is `height:auto`? I can't see either in my style and in bootstrap example style!

Comment: I want the sidebar and mainbar have height 100% bc if not page will be very ugly!

Comment: I know they are 100%. Read the question. The problem is I'm getting extra scroll and I don't know why. actually it shouldn't give me extra scroll when there is nothing to scroll. That's the problem!

Comment: obviously it will show extra scroll to the height, `100% + height of footer = extra scroll`

Comment: How can I have 100% - (height of footer) for main container so the final height will be only 100%?

Comment: make a footer screen fix by `position:fixed; bottom:0;` or layout fix by `position:absolute; bottom:0;`